# How to get all count of all options in a drop down list?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am trying to calculate all the options displayed inside the 'All tools' dropdown menu on https://smallpdf.com/word-to-pdf

So the total count should be 18 but code calculates as 12 for the options displayed inside the drop down menu

when i run the code, can you check this site and help me with correct code for calculating correct count of sub menu items for 'All menu' drop down.

Here is my code and screenshots:
{
driver.get("https://smallpdf.com/word-to-pdf");

driver.manage().window().maximize();

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='smpdf_BsrfvsQ6t09wiN']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);

int count=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 ']//ul[@class='smpdf_2Rdvmu2rysHgyv']/child::li")).size();


System.out.println(count);
}
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozaI7.jpg)

Comment: actually in li also have ul and li tags

Answer (score 0):

Use this `xPath`:

```
//div[@class='smpdf_379Xjwyb9lWVFS smpdf_2-apaRtNmCROQL']//li/ul/li
```

Full code:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='smpdf_BsrfvsQ6t09wiN']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
int count = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='smpdf_379Xjwyb9lWVFS smpdf_2-apaRtNmCROQL']//li/ul/li")).size();

System.out.println(count);
```

Output:

```
18
```

EDIT:

you have asked to show you how I have found the xPath. Here is a screenshot, that shows:

[image: img]

Comment: i have a question How are you getting the above xpath ,under the class='smpdf_379Xjwyb9lWVFS smpdf_2-apaRtNmCROQL' , I can see one ul tag and one 6 li tags in the DOM, can you help me to find it from dom?

Comment: Happy to hear that your problem is solved. I would be grateful if you mark my answer by clicking on the grey check button below downvote button. I'll load also in my answer an prinscreen with xpath. have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is not pointing to the correct options list.

you can find the div of the expected div first and then find the expected list options using the above div element

Edit:
**working code:**

```
    driver.get("https://smallpdf.com/word-to-pdf");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='smpdf_BsrfvsQ6t09wiN']")).click();
    WebElement container=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='smpdf_379Xjwyb9lWVFS smpdf_2-apaRtNmCROQL']"));
    int count=container.findElements(By.xpath(".//li/ul/li")).size();
    System.out.println("Count :"+count);
```

Comment: Probably you will become also 18 as a result, but it is a wrong approach, since author wants a `dropdown` menu options count. Not a footer options count

Comment: Thanks Andrei!! I have updated the answer by changing the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath and code

```
List<WebElement> elemlist= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='smpdf_379Xjwyb9lWVFS smpdf_2-apaRtNmCROQL']//li/ul/li"));
        int count = elemlist.size();
        System.out.println(count);
```